# Turn off autocompletion for management forms

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, forms

In our web application we provide a dashboard that contains a management form for creating and changing user data of the registered users.

The issue is that firefox recognizes two of these fields as login fields and suggests autocompletion for the next visit of this form on submit. We don't want our administrators to receive this suggestion at all because it led to confusion when administrators where shown their own login data in another users change forms.

I tried to follow [MDN suggestions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) on how to deal with autocompletion in this case. They provide the following explanation:

> If a site sets autocomplete="off" for a form, and the form includes username and password input fields, then **the browser will still offer to remember this login**, and if the user agrees, the browser will autofill those fields the next time the user visits the page.

and further this:

> If an author would like to prevent the autofilling of password fields in user management pages where a user can specify a new password for someone other than themself, autocomplete="new-password" should be specified, though support for this has not been implemented in all browsers yet.

Our form currently looks roughly like this but firefox stil keeps offering to autocomplete it.

```
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input id="id_first_name" name="first_name" type="text">
    <label for="id_first_name">First Name</label>

    <input id="id_last_name" name="last_name" type="text">
    <label for="id_last_name">Last Name</label>

    <input id="id_raw_password" name="raw_password" autocomplete="new-password" type="password">
    <label for="id_raw_password">New Password (The current password is not displayed here.)</label>

    <input id="id_email" name="email" type="email">
    <label for="id_email">Email address</label>

    <!-- some more user profile fields like birth date etc. -->
</form>
```

Does anybody have a clue how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

> If an author would like to prevent the autofilling of password fields in user management pages where a user can specify a new password for someone other than themself, autocomplete="new-password" should be specified, though support for this has not been implemented in all browsers yet.

It turns out that firefox is one of these browsers that does not implement it's own recommendations.

A detailed discussion about this can be found on [this bug tracker thread](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1119063#c16).

After discussing this with our fellow developers we decided to not provide a password field for changing other users passwords at all. **Our recommendation in case someone else encounters this problem is to provide a way to send an email to the user that allows him/her to change his/her password him-/herself.** This is maybe even considered a better practice as it makes sure that the users password is never exposed to somebody else then the user himself.